# U-SQL How can i execute Linqu solution that return my Dictionary

Tags: u-sql

I'm have a list with string types and i want to get each one that have maximum of occurence element grouped by another column. I'm trying to do this by linqu expression but it doesn't work. Is it possible to run my code that i show below ?

```
@test=(from a in @data
            group a by new {a.PostCode}
            into obj
            select obj).ToDictionary(x => x.Key,x=>x.ToList()
            .Select(y=>y.Statistic).GroupBy(s => s)
                     .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                     .First().Key);
```

Comment: You can't assign a U-SQL rowset from a LINQ expression as the code above.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results please?

Comment: Is `@data` a rowset? Then use U-SQL and not LINQ. Is `@data` an IEnumerable? Then where does it come from? How does the rowset look like?